# $\min x^TWx$ s.t. $||x||_{\infty} \leq 1, ||x||_2 \leq 1$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Minimize  $(x^TWx)$ s.t $||x||_{\infty} \leq 1, ||x||_2 \leq 1$

Probably  there are many ways to solve this problem, but I am interested in solving this problem via dual formulation. So I started with this:

$L(x,v,k) = x^TWx +v(||x||_{\infty}-1)+k(||x||_2-1)$

$g(v,k) = \inf_x(L(x,v,k))$

Here I dont know how to minimize this function with respect to $x$. I can differentiate $x^TWx$ and $||x||_2$, but how can I deal with $||x||_{\infty}$?

Comment: I think it is better to replace the constraints with $x_k^2\le 1$, $k=1,\ldots, n$ and $x^Tx\le 1$ to get the differentiable $L$.

Comment: @A.Γ. indeed, thanks, I will try that

Comment: Actually, the constraint for $2$-norm implies the one with $\infty$-norm, so it is enough to demand just $x^Tx\le 1$.

Comment: if the bounds on the norm are such that you cannot just omit one norm constraint, you can replace the $\infty$-norm with $2n$ linear constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct various dual formulations, all of them are quite different.
First, you can reformulate the problem as was suggested in the comments into
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min{x} &\quad x^T W x \\
\text{s.t.} 
 &\quad \|x\|_2^2 \leq 1 \\
 &\quad x_i^2 \leq 1 & i = 1, \dots, n
\end{aligned}
$$
And now construct the Lagrangian with the scalar $\lambda \geq 0$ and the non-negative vector $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$
$$
\begin{aligned}
L(x, \lambda, \mu) 
 &= x^T W x + \lambda(\|x\|_2^2 - 1) + \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i (x_i^2 - 1) \\
 &= x^T (W + \lambda I + \operatorname{diag}(\mu))x - \lambda - \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i
\end{aligned}
$$
The minimum is $-\infty$ if at least one eigenvalue of $W + \lambda I + \operatorname{diag}(\mu)$ is negative. Otherwise, the minimum is obtained at $x = 0$ and it is $-\lambda - \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i$. So your dual is a semidefinite program, and I do not see how it is easier than the original.

Another reformulation might be obtained by giving a multiplier only to the constraints $x_i^2 \leq 1$. In that case, the Lagrangian is 
$$
L(x, \mu) = x^T (W + \operatorname{diag}(\mu)) x - \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i
$$
Minimizing $L$ subject to $\|x\|_2^2 \leq 1$ results in 
$$
q(\mu) = \lambda_{\min}(W + \operatorname{diag}(\mu)) - \sum_{i=1}^n \mu_i
$$
and the minimizer is the eigenvector corresponding to the minimum eigenvalue of $W + \operatorname{diag}(\mu)$. Again, can be reformulated as a semidefinite program, and I do not see how it is easier than the primal problem.

Finally, another approach is adding auxiliary variables $y = x$ and $z = x$, resulting in 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x, y, z} &\quad x^T W x \\
\text{s.t.} 
 &\quad -x + y = 0 \\
 &\quad -x + z = 0 \\
 &\quad \|y\|_2 \leq 1 \\
 &\quad \|z\|_\infty \leq 1
\end{aligned}
$$
In that case, giving a multiplier to the first two constraints, we obtain the Lagrangian
$$
L(x, y, z, \lambda, \mu) = x^T W x + \lambda^T(-x + y) + \mu^T(-x + z)
 = x^T W x - (\lambda^T - \mu^T) x + \lambda^T y + \mu^T z
$$
Minimizing the Lagrangian subject to $\|y\|_2 \leq 1$ and $\|z\|_\infty \leq 1$, and noting that we can minimize separately over $x$, $y$ and $z$, we obtain 
$$
q(\lambda, \mu) = \min_x \{  x^T W x - (\lambda^T - \mu^T) x   \} + \min_y \{ \lambda^T y :  \|y\|_2 \leq 1 \} + \min_z \{\mu^T z :  \|z\|_\infty \leq 1 \}
$$
The first minimum is a quadratic function, which is easily obtained, including the minimizer, by comparing the gradient of the term inside $\{ \}$ to zero (if $W$ is positive semidefinite). If $W$ is not PSD, then this dual problem is useless, since the minimum is $-\infty$ regardless of $\lambda$ and $\mu$.
The second minimum is $\|\lambda\|_\infty$, while the third is $\|\mu\|_1$, using our knowledge about dual norms of the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$ norms.
This dual might be useful, but is still hard.